# Apache 2.4 configuration for ssl not working

Tags: https, apache2, tomcat7, mod-jk

Apache Server 2.4 with mod_jk  1.3.7 not working for ssl (https)

**Error 1:**

> > The Apache service named  reported the following error:
> >
> > > SSLSessionCache: 'shmcb' session cache not supported (known names: ). Maybe you need to load the appropriate socache module (mod_socache_shmcb?).

**Error 2:**

> > Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.4.0, time stamp: 0x512fec36
> >     Faulting module name: mod_jk.so, version: 1.2.37.0, time stamp: 0x4fc48072
> >     Exception code: 0xc0000005
> >     Fault offset: 0x000000000000752d
> >     Faulting process id: 0x3580
> >     Faulting application start time: 0x01cee6d2be493d71
> >     Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\bin\httpd.exe
> >     Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.4\modules\mod_jk.so
> >     Report Id: f8d090fa-52c6-11e3-bce9-e4d53d737212

Our configuration for `httpd_ssl.conf` is as follows:

```
Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/htdocs"
ServerName 127.0.0.1:443
ServerAdmin admin@mshome.net
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/conf/serverssl.crt"

SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/conf/server.key"

SSLCACertificateFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/conf/bundle.crt"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/logs/ssl_request.log" \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

TIA....!

Answer (score 130, accepted):

In Apache2.2 following line is uncommented in `apache/conf/httpd.conf` by default.

> > LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so

From Apache 2.4 above line is commented so remove the `#` sign before it.

This should work.

Comment: for newbie visit [link](http://urattarde.blogspot.in/2013/11/making-website-https-using-apachehttpd.html). regarding same issues

Comment: You may need to change the link of `modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so` to where the shared object lives.  Mine was at `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it saves my time

Comment: I uncomment the line and the problem persists, what to do?

Comment: @FábioZangirolami Are you getting the same error as OP got? Are you using Apache 2.4?

Comment: @VarunVerma Thanks for adding the information :) Please mention your Apache version, it will be helpful for others.

Comment: This solution got me in the right direction but didn't work exactly for my apache version (Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)). I had to link the module socache_shmcb.load into mods-enabled and that resolved the problem for me.

Comment: On apache 2.4.25-3+deb9u4 that line doesn't exists. You must create a symbolic link pointing to the module enabling it in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` this way:
`ln -s ../mods-available/socache_shmcb.load socache_shmcb.load`

Answer (score 9):

On apache 2.4.25-3+deb9u4 (Debian obviously) the line mentioned by @Mr Roshan Pawar doesn't exists. You must create a symbolic link pointing to the module and enabling it in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` this way:

`ln -s ../mods-available/socache_shmcb.load socache_shmcb.load`

As @ericP said it's neccesary to restart your apache, depending on your distro/config it could be:

```
service apache2 restart
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
systemctl restart apache2
apache2 -k restart
```

Comment: You might need to do a brutal reload after this. I tried a graceful reload (`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`) and still saw "'shmcb' session cache not supported". It worked with a `stop` and a `start`.

Comment: Thanks  @ericP, that's true, it is necessary to restart, reloading will only "refresh" applied changes, in this case we are adding something "new" (which is the new module being activated) into our Apache. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For el capitan the path to `so` file is `/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_socache_shmcb.so`,

my entry in `httpd.conf` looked like:

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

Answer (score 3):

For Apache 2.4. at Ubuntu:

```
sudo a2enmod socache_shmcb
```

Answer (score 2):

cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/socache_shmcb.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

This will fix: 
SSLSessionCache: 'shmcb' session cache not supported (known names: ). Maybe you need to load the appropriate socache module (mod_socache_shmcb?).

Comment: Terrible practice to copy the binary, the correct way is to point a symbolic link.